# Unknown Key error making nautilus sluggish

Tags: nautilus, 22.10

So, since I updated to 22.10 I was getting the feeling that nautilus is being slightly sluggish. So I tried to check if I was imagining things, and got this error. Any idea how to fix this or what's causing this? Thanks!!

```
$ time nautilus   

 (org.gnome.Nautilus:22059): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:11:30:719: Unknown key gtk-button-images in /home/<myusername>/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
    (org.gnome.Nautilus:22059): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:11:30:719: Unknown key gtk-button-images in /home/<myusername>/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
    (org.gnome.Nautilus:22059): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:11:30:719: Unknown key gtk-button-images in /home/<myusername>/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini
```

Comment: Look into `/home/<myusername>/.config/gtk-4.0/settings.ini` and try to remove that key.

Comment: Yeah, I did that initially. But the error was recurring after every Ubuntu base update in 22.10.But it seems like that last update yesterday fixed the issue for me.